# Apache ImportError when loading django module WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am following the [integration with django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) tutorial on the mod_wsgi site, and I am receiving the following error when trying to load my site, I had the test script in the previous [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) working fine. Here is the error log from my apache server, I have django installed fine, I can import it when I am running python so I assume it must be something else that is the cause of the broken link.

```
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:14 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] mod_wsgi (pid=1851): Target       WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts$
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] mod_wsgi (pid=1851): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/va$
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103]   File "/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/test.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] mod_wsgi (pid=1853): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts$
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] mod_wsgi (pid=1853): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/va$
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103]   File "/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/test.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Mon Jul 25 20:44:15 2011] [error] [client 93.97.146.103] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Does anyone have any idea of what this is? my httpd/apache configuration is just basic at the moment as highlighted in the second tutorial.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either install Django under the version of Python that mod_wsgi is built against, or build mod_wsgi for the version of Python that Django is installed under.